# Mutliple users can access sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I am doing static code analysis. And I using with sonarqube. Currently I am login as a administrator.

> Is it possible to access mutliple users login?

I want to report the code anaysis to my team members. is it possible ? 
Is there any rule we can give our rule like code commenting ?

Comment: Have you tried to search for SonarQube Documentation? Do they say they support such a feature?

Comment: why you need to login with multiple users? Your team-mates needs to be log-in and they can see.. What needs to be improve in respective check-ins

Comment: @NarendraC  If my team members want to see. they should be install sonar-runner then only they can access right ?

Comment: No need to install - Just log-in on web portal

Answer (score 1):

My SonarQube web-based instance has a menu "Administration" when I am logged in as the Admin users.

On the Administration page there is dropdown "Security" which has the following items:

- Users
- Groups
- Global Permissions
- Project Permissions
- Permission Templates

Here you can setup users and permissions, so yes you can use multiple user logins.

[image]

Comment: I got the same page but i want to acces another system what should I do ?  or

Comment: i install LDAP then I did To force user authentication,But can't acces to my team mebers what should I do ?

Comment: Why don't you start with the basic user management saved in the SQL database? Why add another layer of complexity with LDAP? :) Keep it simple, wonder if you really need LDAP now, cant it wait until you figured out if SonarQube is the tool for you and your team. Why waste time on a nice to have? Maybe even just share the admin account for simplicity sake.

Comment: I already install LDAP . LDAP for create a user.  you said that don't use ldap. But i want to  access sonarqube to my team members.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple user login in SonarCube:**

> Is it possible to access multiple users login?

- Its not required as you just wanted to report code analysis to all team members
- All team members needs to log-in with their emails and respective member can see improvements needed for their check-ins
- As a Administrator, you will have access to see graphical representation of individual team-mates open and close items

Comment: i install LDAP  then I did To force user authentication,But can't acces to my temmebers what should I do ?